# non-matching XRef stream entry size

Tags: pdf, stream, cross-reference

I'm trying to read an XRef stream object but something doesn't adds up. This is my object:

```
<<
/DecodeParms << /Columns 5/Predictor 12 >>
/Filter /FlateDecode
/ID [<9597C618BC90AFA4A078CA72B2DD061C><48726007F483D547A8BEFF6E9CDA072F>]
/Index [124332 848]
/Info 124331 0 R
/Length 137
/Prev 8983958
/Root 124333 0 R
/Size 125180
/Type /XRef
/W [1 3 1]
>>
```

I read the 137 bytes of stream, uncompress them through zlib and I get 5088 bytes. This is the beginning of the uncompressed stream (hexdump -C output):

```
00000000  02 01 00 00 10 00 02 00  00 27 ec 00 02 00 00 01  |.........'......|
00000010  f4 00 02 00 00 01 f7 00  02 00 00 04 5b 00 02 00  |............[...|
00000020  00 02 68 00 02 00 00 0b  ac 00 02 00 00 0f e5 00  |..h.............|
00000030  02 00 00 0e 93 00 02 00  00 0d 14 00 02 00 00 0d  |................|
```

What I don't understand is that I should have 5 bytes per entry: /W [1 3 1] means 1+3+1=5 bytes; but the stream's length of 5088 isn't divisible by 5. Also, I realized that 5088 is divisible by 6: 5088/6=848 and that's the number of entry as the second value of the /Index key confirms. Reading the stream keeping the [1 3 1] scheme is, also, impossible already at the second entry (the byte 0xEC isn't a valid entry type).
Where's my mistake?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

After decompression each line has 6 bytes: 1 byte for predictor, 5 for 'predicted' data. 
After you apply the predictor you get the actual data.